# Odd behaviour when picking a random integer from range

Tags: javascript

The user supplies a range, say 3-5. The script should produce a random integer in that range. Now, this code works fine.

```
length = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 3 + 1)) + 3;
```

However, if I programatically extract the values from the range and do the same, the results are nonsense.

```
//Split into elements
var range = lengthval.split("-"),
    minlen = range[0],
    maxlen = range[1];

if (!isNaN(minlen) && !isNaN(maxlen)) {
    //Pick a number from range
    length = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxlen - minlen + 1)) + minlen;
}
```

The really weird thing is that the following "hybrid" snippet works fine.

```
//Split into elements
var range = lengthval.split("-"),
    minlen = range[0],
    maxlen = range[1];

if (!isNaN(minlen) && !isNaN(maxlen)) {
    //Pick a number from range
    length = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxlen - minlen + 1)) + 3;
}
```

Given that the range supplied is 3-5 of course.

Could anyone help a fresh javascript developer figure this one out? :)

Comment: You should probably work with numbers and not strings. `minlen = Number(range[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `lengthval` is I'm fairly certain you will need to use `parseInt`

```
minlen = parseInt(range[0], 10)
maxlen = parseInt(range[1], 10)
```

Comment: Don't forget to use a radix _just in case_

Comment: You're absolutely right! Glad the solution was that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are, thanks to and updated from @depperm:

```js
//Split into elements
var range = '3-5'.split("-");
minlen = Number(range[0]);
maxlen = Number(range[1]);
var length;
if (!isNaN(minlen) && !isNaN(maxlen)) {
  //Pick a number from range
  length = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxlen - minlen + 1)) + minlen;
  alert(length);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse the Strings you get from `split` into numbers

```
var range = "3-5".split("-");
var minlen = parseInt(range[0]);
var maxlen = parseInt(range[1]);
if (!isNaN(minlen) && !isNaN(maxlen))  {
      //Pick a number from range
      var length = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxlen - minlen + 1)) + minlen;
}
```

also declare your variables (use `var`) and end your statements with a semicolon.

http://jsfiddle.net/ks3hrzbL/